# How to access to a field of a dynamic type?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I'm trying to wrap the results of a query with a class called `QueryResultViewModel` from a list of `dynamic` objects retrieved by LINQ. These contain a integer field called `Worked`. I should not use a non-dynamic type because depending on the query it has other fields. I tried that:

```
    var query = new HoursQuery( .. parameters .. );
    this.Result = new ObservableCollection<QueryResultViewModel>(
      query.Execute().Select( x => new QueryResultViewModel( x.Worked )));
```

But I got "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Worked'" and I don't know If it can be fixed without changing query's return type.

The Execute code may be useful too:

```
    var res = some_list.GroupBy(a => new { a.Employee, a.RelatedTask, a.Start.Month })
       .Select(g => new { K = g.Key, Worked = g.Sum(s => s.Duration.TotalHours) });
```

**EDIT**: This worked great but maybe it's not very elegant.

```
    public class HQueryDTO
    {
        public double Worked;
        public object K;
    }

    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Execute()
    {
        var list = base.Execute();
        return res = list.GroupBy(a => new { a.Employee, a.RelatedTask } )
          .Select(g => new HQueryDTO { K = g.Key, Worked = g.Sum(s => s.Duration.TotalHours) });
    }
```

Now that the result has a type it can be returned dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *assuming* you get that error at compile-time, in which case simply introduce `dynamic` via a cast:

```
.Select(x => new QueryResultViewModel( ((dynamic)x).Worked ))
```

Comment: Nope. The error is runtime trying to access worked. I can't yet answer my own questions but I edit it with new info.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the signature of `Execute` is something like  `object Execute()`. If you return `dynamic`, it should work.